# Странный WARNING при старте spring-boot-data-mongodb приложения

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

При старте приложения в логе присутствует вот такой Warning:

```html
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/home/dragon/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.9.RELEASE/9f9a828936d81afd49a603bda9cc1aed863a0d85/spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

О чём это предупреждение и как его избежать?

Вот содержимое build.gradle:

```html
buildscript {
 ext {
  springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
 }
 repositories {
  mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
 }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'net.chemodurov'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
 compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
 testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Это [баг](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15859) в Spring 5.0.x, который проявляется начиная с Java 9 и уже исправлен в готовящемся к скорому релизу Spring 5.1. Вы используете Spring Boot 2.0.5, у которого в зависимостях Spring 5.0.9. Если это предупреждение вам мешает, дождитесь выхода Spring Boot 2.1, с которым в зависимостях получите Spring 5.1.0. Заодно обновите и Java до так же выходящей через несколько дней Java 11. Java 11 - первая LTS (Long Time Support) версия, после изменения политики выхода новых версий Java, начиная с Java 9.